# Client application not able to connect to the second tibco server when the first tibco server is down

Tags: jms, tibco

I have an application that acts as a listener to the configured tibco server.
My requirement is I should have 2 tibco servers defined in my app and if one of the server goes down, the application should connect itself to the second configured server.
For the same, I did the changes as mentioned below :

```
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tibjmsnaming://${HOST}:${PORT},tibjmsnaming://${FAILOVER_HOST}:${FAILOVER_PORT}</prop>
```

where the values for HOST, PORT, FAILOVER_HOST and FAILOVER_PORT are coming from the properties file.

Below mentioned piece of code is used to create the connection :

```
    public void init() throws JMSException { 
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)initConnectionFactory(connectionParameters);
    
            session = connection.createSession(TRANSACTIONS_ENABLED, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            DestinationResolver destinationResolver = new DynamicDestinationResolver();
            Destination destination = destinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(session, connectionParameters.destination, false);
            messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);
        }
```

I found we can achieve the same using mule. But my application is not supposed to use mule.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem was, as your question doesn't really specify that but in order to connect to TIBCO EMS you can generally take two steps

1) Perform a JNDI lookup to get the server address you want to connect to (this is optional if you already know the exact address)
2) Connect to the server and start sending messages

For step 1, the [TIBCO EMS documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.4.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.4_users_guide.pdf?id=1) (pages 401 through 403) provides a good overview on how to do that in Java:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
"com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tibjmsnaming://jmshost:7222,
tibjmsnaming://backuphost:7222");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.tibco.tibjms.naming")
env.put(TibjmsContext.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
env.put(TibjmsContext.SSL_ENABLE_VERIFY_HOST,
new Boolean("false"));
Context context = new InitialContext(env);
```

From that context object you can start to send messages and this is where the URLs you had in your question would be required (starting with **tibjmsnaming**).

For step 2, or if you already have the URLs that resolve to the JMS servers you want to send messages to, you'll need something like:

```
    String serverURL = "tcp://server1,tcp://server2"
    ConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
    connection = factory.createConnection(userName, password);
    session = connection.createSession(javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    destination = session.createTopic(topicName);
    msgProducer = session.createProducer(null);
    msg = session.createTextMessage();
    msg.setText(messageStr);
    msgProducer.send(destination, msg);
```

If I recall correctly, the TIBCO EMS installation comes with a bunch of really good Java samples that cover both sending and receiving messages for Fault-Tolerant pairs as well as for single instance servers.

Comment: The requirement is that there are two tibco servers that are not configured in a fault tolerant way (they don't share state, nor they are aware of the existence of each other). My application has got both these servers listed under the property "java.naming.provider.url" as shown above. When one of the server goes down, the application should make an attempt to connect to the second server.

Comment: In that case you might want to check out the "Configuring Clients for Unshared State Failover Connections", which seems to cover what your requirement is(page 532 and on in the EMS documentation).